# Issues accessing and modifying array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to create a program which allows the user to remove staff with a specified payroll numbers.

The program should function as follows:

Program displays current staff in the arraylist before asking the user for input of a payroll number they'd like to remove. User then inputs the payroll number of one of the three staff members and presses enter. Upon pressing enter, the program should remove that particular staff member from the array list and display the entire list again (missing out the staff member they've deleted obviously). If they do not wish to remove any payroll numbers, the payroll number entry should be `0` and should then display the contents of the list again.

I have the following files and structure:

**--- EDIT --- : ArrayListTest.java**

```
import java.util.*;

import personnelPackage.Personnel;

public class ArrayListTest
{
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long searchQuery;

        ArrayList<Personnel> staffList = new ArrayList<Personnel>();
        Personnel[] staff =
            {new Personnel(123456,"Smith","John"),
             new Personnel(234567,"Jones","Sally Ann"),
             new Personnel(999999,"Black","James Paul")};

        for (Personnel person:staff)
            staffList.add(person);

        do
        {
            showDisplay(staffList);

            System.out.print("\nPlease enter a payroll number to search: ");
            searchQuery = keyboard.nextLong();

            searchForPayrollNumber(staffList, searchQuery);


        }while(!(searchQuery == 0));


    }

    private static void showDisplay(ArrayList<Personnel> staffList)
    {
        System.out.print("\n------------- CURRENT STAFF LIST -------------\n");
        for (Personnel person : staffList)
        {
            System.out.println("Payroll number: " + person.getPayNum());
            System.out.println("Surname: " + person.getSurname());
            System.out.println("First name(s): " + person.getFirstNames() + "\n");
        }
    }

    public static void searchForPayrollNumber(ArrayList<Personnel> staffList, long searchQuery)
    {
        long index = staffList.indexOf(searchQuery);;

        for (Personnel person: staffList)
        {
            if (person.getPayNum() == searchQuery)
            {               
                System.out.print("\n------------- Staff member found and removed! -------------");
                System.out.println("\n\nFirst Name(s): " + person.getFirstNames());
                System.out.println("\nSurname: " + person.getSurname());
                System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------------");

                staffList.remove(index);
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\n------------- No staff members found. Program terminated -------------");
        return;

    }

}
```

**Personnel.java** (in its own package named `personnelPackage`)

```
package personnelPackage;

public class Personnel
{
    private long payrollNum;
    private String surname;
    private String firstNames;

    public Personnel(long payrollNum, String surname, String firstNames)
    {
        this.payrollNum = payrollNum;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.firstNames = firstNames;
    }

    public long getPayNum()
    {
        return payrollNum;
    }

    public String getSurname()
    {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getFirstNames()
    {
        return firstNames;
    }

    public void setSurname(String newName)
    {
        surname = newName;
    }
}
```

My program at the minute only recognises the first staff member if I enter the payroll number. Any other staff member does not get 'found'. Where am I going wrong with this? How can I remove a specific payroll number from the array and ask the user for another input (until the array is "empty").

Comment: output of showDisplay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `return` statement in your `else` block.

```
    for (Personnel person: staff)
    {
        if (person.getPayNum() == searchQuery)
        {
            System.out.print("\n------------- Staff member found! -------------");
            System.out.println("\n\nFirst Name(s): " + person.getFirstNames());
            System.out.println("Surname: " + person.getSurname());
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("\n------------- No staff members found -------------");
            return;  // Remove this one.
        }
    }
```

By having a return statement in each branch of the conditional, this loop will only ever execute once.

Note that you probably also want to move the contents of the `else` outside the loop, otherwise you will be told "No staff members found" for every person checked.

```
    for (Personnel person: staff)
    {
        if (person.getPayNum() == searchQuery)
        {
            System.out.print("\n------------- Staff member found! -------------");
            System.out.println("\n\nFirst Name(s): " + person.getFirstNames());
            System.out.println("Surname: " + person.getSurname());
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n------------- No staff members found -------------");
```

---

*Edit for your question about removing the element:*

Your current code will not work: `indexOf` will return -1, because the list contains `Personnel` instances, not payroll numbers. And if this did work, you wouldn't need to then iterate the list to find the element again: you already know where it is in the list.

To do efficient removal, you need to use an `Iterator`; an enhanced for loop won't work. The rough implementation looks like:

```
Iterator<Personnel> it = staff.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Personnel person = it.next();
  if (person.getPayNum() == searchQuery)
```

{
        // ... Print etc
        it.remove();
        return;
      }
    }

Comment: Thanks for this fantastic answer! How can I make it so that it removes the found staff member from the list? (in `searchForPayrollNumber`) would I have to pass in the `ArrayList` instead of the `staff` array? Would you be able to show me how this can be done?

Comment: Edited, but please don't tack on riders to your question in future: ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `return;` statements from your search. This instructs the jvm to return from method.

```
 if (person.getPayNum() == searchQuery)
            {
                System.out.print("\n------------- Staff member found! -------------");
                System.out.println("\n\nFirst Name(s): " + person.getFirstNames());
                System.out.println("Surname: " + person.getSurname());
                // return; // This return is optional, won't interfere with your business. 
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("\n------------- No staff members found -------------");
                // return; // This one has to be removed for proper function.
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is it possible for me to remove that found 'person' from the list? (Please see my edited code in the main question for `ArrayListTest`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "return" in your if/else. When you return in the else the main method stops. So if the searched person is not the first one, the method ends.  Just remove the else clause and put the print outside the for loop.

```
    for (Personnel person: staff)
    {

        if (person.getPayNum() == searchQuery)
        {
            System.out.print("\n------------- Staff member found! -------------");
            System.out.println("\n\nFirst Name(s): " + person.getFirstNames());
            System.out.println("Surname: " + person.getSurname());
            return;
        }



    }
    System.out.print("\n------------- No staff members found -------
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is it possible for me to remove that found 'person' from the list? (Please see my edited code in the main question for `ArrayListTest`)

Comment: Do not edit your question to a complete new one. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

in your above code you `return` in else block. remove return statement from else block so that loop will execute. here loop is not excuting because in elese block then is return statement.

```
    public static int searchForPayrollNumber(Personnel[] staff)
    {
int i=0;
        long searchQuery;

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a payroll number to search: ");
        searchQuery = keyboard.nextLong();

        for (Personnel person: staff)
        {

            if (person.getPayNum() == searchQuery)
            {
                System.out.print("\n------------- Staff member found! -------------");
                System.out.println("\n\nFirst Name(s): " + person.getFirstNames());
                System.out.println("Surname: " + person.getSurname());
                i++;    
                break;
            }

        }
return i;

    }
```

in above function check value of method return. if it is 0 then no record found.